# This program is error free. Or error-free?

Tags: american-english, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Which one is correct in American English:

> This computer program is error-free.
>
> This computer program is error free.

... and why? Are, perhaps, both correct?  If so, is there any difference in the meaning? (Aside: we do not speak about "an error{ |-}free program" or "a program free of errors" here. The post-position of "whatever{ |-}free" is intentional.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the *Chicago Manual of Style* § 7.89(3), "[c]ompounds formed with free as second element are hyphenated both before and after a noun." The examples given are "toll-free number" and "accident-free driver."

Specifically, in the construction you listed, the examples are:

"The number is *toll-free*." and "The driver is *accident-free*."

Therefore, "The program is *error-free*." would be the proper construction under the *Chicago Manual* though other style-guides may say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=error-free%2Cerror+free&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cerror%20-%20free%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cerror%20free%3B%2Cc0) both possibilities are correct, although it might be better to use the hyphen. In British English it is often the case that both forms of a compound are used. Nevertheless, as a trend started more than twenty years ago people tend to use more hyphens in this type of English.

*Complement*

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+error-free%2Cbe+error+free%2Cis+error-free%2Cis+error+free&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20error%20-%20free%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbe%20error%20free%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20error%20-%20free%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20error%20free%3B%2Cc0) showing usage in the case of predicative use.

Comment: @Just_A_Man "error-free", "error free" and "free of error" are synonymous although their place in the noun phrase differs and this is, almost without doubt, true in American English too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, "error free" need not be "error-free" in all cases. The British, especially sources such as the Guardian, prefer "error free" to the latter.

Comment: Would help if you gave some examples with links where you found them...